# Third Party Risk Management: Validating responses from vendors?

Tags: risk-management, third-party

I am designing a 3PRM (Third-Party Risk Management) process in a FS company, and I'm curious about how other companies validate their supplier questionnaires.

The system I'm anticipating is (after I've issued supplier questionnaires, and received the responses) dividing up the responses for degrees of validation.

I'm considering three tiers:

**Tier 1**: Suppliers that can be assured based purely on their questionnaire responses: that is, given the level of risk to the company, we don't require anything more than the answers to the questionnaires (plus copies of any certifications that they claim to have, such as ISO27001, etc)

**Tier 2**: Suppliers that we require additional evidence in order to be assured that they are secure: that is, we might need to see (for example) copies of the policies that they claim to be upholding, plus evidence that they are being upheld, etc.

**Tier 3**: Suppliers will require a site visit to verify their responses: that is, suppliers that represent a sufficient risk that we need to be certain that they are secure, by checking it for ourselves.

My questions would be:

1. What criteria should we use to distinguish between these three tiers? What sort of benchmarks or cut-offs would be appropriate (based on risk to the company, the kinds of service being supplied, etc)?
2. What kinds of evidence would be reasonable to ask for in relation to Tier 2 suppliers?

Comment: You kind of answer your own question: based on risk, what *assurance* do you require to be confident that the risk levels are at the levels they assert? I think you might need to liaise with your audit dept since they design assurance processes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing "FS" is Financial Services. Although I don't have experience in that industry, I've worked with similar processes in other industries and can outline what I've seen, both from the companies that I've worked for as well as from the companies that use us as a vendor.

The first step is typically an internal assessment. You build a business case, identifying why you need a vendor. You'll identify one or more possible vendors as well. If you have the capability to build, a build-vs-buy decision may be part of this internal assessment as well. This is often based on publicly available information to narrow down the scope and determine which vendors to engage with. This would also look at the intended use of the product or service and what, if any, additional work is necessary.

If the internal assessment requires a further assessment from a quality perspective (meaning more than just engaging with the vendor's sales teams to negotiate a contract), the next step would be a standard questionnaire. Many of the questions have overlap with various standards like ISO27001, SOC2, etc. If the organization has such a certification, I typically expect to see the answer indicating that the question is addressed by the certification report (and if they are really nice, citing a specific section or sections that I could read). If they do not have an appropriate certification that covers the case, then I would expect a specific answer to the question.

Based on the risks identified in the internal assessment and the answers to the questionnaire in the second step (which may include internal certifications), the third step would be an audit. This typically happens if the vendor doesn't have the relevant certifications. Except for the highest risk systems, a questionnaire plus relevant certification almost always eliminates the need for an audit.

The differences in what you propose and what I've often seen is that Tier 1 is something that doesn't require significant assessment or certification - the lowest criticality and risk vendors. Tier 2 receives a questionnaire, and they would be expected to produce relevant certification reports or undergo an assessment. Tier 3 would undergo an assessment, either due to lack of certification, questions raised by the certification report, or the level of risk identified in the initial vendor assessment. I'd point out that assessments may be done virtually, such as over Microsoft Teams, WebEx, or some other conferencing application.

The biggest differentiation is a risk. It's up to you to define what you consider to be your risks, though, and how much tolerance you have for different kinds of risk. Things like the cost of the product or service, the impact of not having access to the product or service, how integrated the product or service is to your core business are all some examples of things that you would have to consider. I'm not sure that anyone here could tell you what is most concerning to you other than you.

Just like we can't tell you how to perform a risk assessment, I'm not sure that we can tell you what evidence to collect if you were to perform your own assessment. As someone who has performed vendor assessments, I usually leave it up to the vendor to provide a description of their process, ideally before the assessment so I have time to review it. Then, at the assessment, I want to see how many times the process has been executed and a sampling of evidence from it. I leave the generation and demonstration of evidence up to the organization being assessed since it's their process and they know best how to demonstrate it.